# Where are are views controllers in the storyboard initiated?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a [main view controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0TGU.jpg) in the main story board. I want this controller to have a state when it is initiated. I need to know where this view controller is initiated so that I can change its constructor to the following custom constructor. Can someone help me out?

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil{
       self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
       if (self) {
       self.state= @"login";}
  return self;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

View controllers in a storyboard are not instantiated using that initializer.  They are instantiated using `initWithCoder:`.

```
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:decoder]) {
        self.state = @"login";
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: is there a way to change it to a custom initializer? Should I just overwrite the initWithCoder initializer?

Comment: Yes. Just override initWithCode. Don't forget to call super

Comment: I have amended my answer.